# Is there a trick for SMUI dialog to be shown on demand only?

Tags: svelte

Like dialogs on the demo page https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/dialog/.
If i place code of an example dialog in 'App.svelte' of bare TS+rollup based project, then it displays both dialog contents (althought shouldn't because bound 'open' variable defaults to false) and dialog call button.

## App.svelte

```
<Dialog
  bind:open
  aria-labelledby="simple-title"
  aria-describedby="simple-content"
  target="mumu"
>
  <!-- Title cannot contain leading whitespace due to mdc-typography-baseline-top() -->
  <Title id="simple-title">Dialog Title</Title>
  <Content id="simple-content">Super awesome dialog body text?</Content>
  <Actions>
    <Button on:click={() => (clicked = 'No')}>
      <Label>No</Label>
    </Button>
    <Button on:click={() => (clicked = 'Yes')}>
      <Label>Yes</Label>
    </Button>
  </Actions>
</Dialog>


<Button on:click={() => (open = true)}>
  <Label>Open Dialog</Label>
</Button>

<pre class="status">Clicked: {clicked}</pre>

<script lang="ts">
  import Dialog, { Title, Content, Actions } from '@smui/dialog';
  import Button, { Label } from '@smui/button';
  import Card from '@smui/card';

  let open = false;
  let clicked = 'Nothing yet.';
</script>

<style>
  :global(.mdc-dialog) {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

</style>
```

[image: how it looks in browser]

Comment: It was probably you opening this issue? https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/issues/454 Got it solved by adding the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, it requires a proper MUI theme to be active.

Answer (score 1):

Surround your `<Dialog>...</Dialog>` with the svelte version of an if block like this:

```
{#if open}
  <Dialog>
    ...
  </Dialog>
{/if}
```

Comment: No, the dialog is supposed to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone following along, this happening because the SMUI dialog component was installed and instantiated in the project, but the theme was not regenerated, so it is not rendered properly.

At the root of your project run:

```
nom run prepare
```